# Centos Directadmin Dovecot Exim, Forward Email From a Different Email Address

Tags: centos, exim, procmail

I am trying to set up a Facebook group so anyone can send email to a specific address and this gets forwarded to our groups address and so is posted in the group.

However unfortunately if you just forward the email the from address is incorrect as Facebook only accepts my person email.

On my web server my email account is set up using DirectAdmin on Postfix (I believe).

Basically either through DirectAdmin or in the config of my mail (through shell), is it possible to set up an email account that any mail send to it is forwarded from **that** account?

As in:
If `steve@google.com` sends an email to `forward@pezcuckow.com` that email is forwarded to `secret@groups.facebook.com` but the from address is `forward@pezcuckow.com`?

At the moment the from address would be `steve@google.com`

The server uses Dovecot and Exim for mail

Sorry for the hard to explain question, I hope you get what I mean!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should login to Directadmin with a user account, go to "Email Management" -> "Email forwarders" and add a forward there.